GTM dataLayer.push isn't working if sent straight before or after gtm initialisation
I want to send some data to GTM as soon as possible.
I tried to call the dataLayer.push before the tag initialisation, after it and inside an initialisation script.
All the 3 ways failed.
<head>
...

// Version 1
<script defer>
    if (!navigator.isServer) {
        var MIXPANEL_PROXY_DOMAIN = 'https://#mixpanelProxyDomain#.crexi.com';
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l !== 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.type = 'text/javascript';
            j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', '#gtmAccountId#');

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'partyTownEnabled': true,
            event: 'Partytown_ready'
        });
    }
</script>

// Version 2
<script defer>
    if (!navigator.isServer) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'partyTownEnabled': true,
            event: 'Partytown_ready'
        });
        var MIXPANEL_PROXY_DOMAIN = 'https://#mixpanelProxyDomain#.crexi.com';
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l !== 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.type = 'text/javascript';
            j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', '#gtmAccountId#');

    }
</script>

// Version 3
<script defer>
    if (!navigator.isServer) {
        var MIXPANEL_PROXY_DOMAIN = 'https://#mixpanelProxyDomain#.crexi.com';
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
            w[l].push({
              'partyTownEnabled': true,
              event: 'Partytown_ready'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l !== 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.type = 'text/javascript';
            j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', '#gtmAccountId#');
    }
</script>

...
</head>

The partyTownEnabled variable exists.
The custom event trigger for Partytown_ready exists.
The tag is bound to the Partytown_ready trigger.
Removing defer/async does nothing.
When I am running it from the Google dev tools console like this dataLayer.push({ 'partyTownEnabled': true, event: 'Partytown_ready' }); it is working as expected.
I thought gtm is designed so to pick up all the predefined dataLayer elements before monkey patching it but it seems not working

FWIW, I tried your first version (only difference is a fixed GTM id) and it worked just fine as one would expect. So there might be some context missing to debug this.

Second version would not ne expected to work (events before the gtm.js has initalised will not be processed. Likewise for version 3, which also will cause confusion internally.)

Thank you for testing, yeah, I expected it should actually work. Something is probably trespassing and breaking how gtm is working. BTW first and second should work just the same because script loading is async and w[l] = w[l] || []; so dataLayers created before should be included

It seems there is an issue with a partytown library and GTM integration.
https://github.com/BuilderIO/partytown/issues/596
Closing this question as a partytown bug.
